# Working with Bengali Font in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I am working on an dictionary software in Java. I am using `JEditorPane`, `JComboBox` and `JTextField` to display and user input. Some of the characters in Bengali seems ok but some does not. I've set the fonts of the component like this:

```
    Font banglaFont=new Font("Kalpurush", Font.PLAIN, 16);
    jEditorPane1.setFont(banglaFont); 
    jTextField1.setFont(banglaFont); 
    jComboBox1.setFont(banglaFont);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshots.  Huh.. that is most strange!

Comment: Please help...anyone has any solution yet? i have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

- no idea without your test, specific language with specific font (I'm used kalpurush ANSI.ttf)
- better could be, have to post (edit your question with) tested sentence in your question, not image
- everything in my PC is setted to English-US, compiler to UTF-8, Java7, Win8.1 (but I'm sure that valid for Win7/WinXP, compiled in Java5/6/7)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;

public class SystemFontDisplayer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nimbus UIDeafaults and Font");
    private JComboBox fontsBox;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;
    private JButton testButton = new JButton("testButton");
    private JTextField testTextField = new JTextField("testTextField");
    private JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("testLabel");
    private Font font1, font2;
    private JMenuBar menuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Menu 1");
    private JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Menu 2");
    private JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("MenuItem 1");
    private JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("MenuItem 2");

    public SystemFontDisplayer() {
        try {
            font1 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, SystemFontDisplayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/Images/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf"));
            font2 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, SystemFontDisplayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/Images/kalpurush ANSI.ttf"));
        } catch (FontFormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SystemFontDisplayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SystemFontDisplayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        //ge.registerFont(font1);
        ge.registerFont(font2);
        String[] fontFamilyNames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(Locale.getDefault());
        fontsBox = new JComboBox(fontFamilyNames);
        fontsBox.setSelectedItem(0);
        //fontsBox.setRenderer(new ComboRenderer());

        fontsBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component result = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
                        value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                final Object fntObj = value;
                final String fontFamilyName = (String) fntObj;
                setFont(new Font(fontFamilyName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
                return result;
            }
        });/**/
        fontsBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    final String fontName = fontsBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    fontsBox.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
                    start();
                }
            }
        });
        fontsBox.setSelectedItem(0);
        fontsBox.getEditor().selectAll();
        menu1.add(menuItem1);
        menuBar1.add(menu1);
        menu2.add(menuItem2);
        menuBar1.add(menu2);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar1);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0, 20, 20));
        frame.add(fontsBox);
        frame.add(testButton);
        frame.add(testTextField);
        frame.add(testLabel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(200, 105);
        frame.pack();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fontsBox.setPopupVisible(true);
                fontsBox.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(750, updateCol());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final Font fnt = new Font(fontsBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), Font.PLAIN, 16);
                final FontUIResource res = new FontUIResource(fnt);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.font", res);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextField.font", res);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Label.font", res);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                frame.pack();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        /*try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
         } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }*/
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemFontDisplayer systemFontDisplayer = new SystemFontDisplayer();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ComboRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            final Object fntObj = value;
            final String fontFamilyName = (String) fntObj;
            setFont(new Font(fontFamilyName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kalpurush ANSI is not the same as Kalpurush.ttf

Comment: @Pranjal Choladhara my question is if that works correctly or not, this isn't an answer, there are a few fonts for your language, I'm download 1st one in order gave me by google, have to test and to use proper one